# Does gradient buttons in web application comply with accessibility?

Tags: accessibility, wcag

Does anybody know if gradient buttons in web application comply with WCAG accessibility rules? We are working on high contrast mode for web application and I can't find any guidelines for that. Can we keep them or plain colors only should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're color scheme passes color blind tests for accessibility, you should be alright. if you focus on a perceivable color scheme, users with color blind deficiencies should still be able to see contrast(s).

Answer (score 1):

As albert stated, check for colour blindness, mainly in males and that you have a contrast of at least 4.5:1 for small to medium text and 3.5:1 for larger text (if not aaa). The Firefox add-on called colour-checker will assist in this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say check the contrast between the background and each of your gradient colours individually. Also make sure that the gradient colours have a 4.5 contrast with the button text. It's tough, I know, I've been working on it for days. but it looks like that's the only way